# Can't use IsSelected as Trigger, but it has a internal get accessor

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, menuitem

When I try to create a Style Trigger onto MenuItem and use the IsSelected Property as a Trigger, I get the error:

> 'IsSelected' cannot be set as the value of a Trigger's Property attribute because it does not have a public or internal get accessor. [...]

My Style is defined like this (error is on the 3rd line, on `Property="IsSelected"`):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And I checked the reference source for the implementation of menuItem.

It is indeed internal:

```
    ///     True if this MenuItem is the current MenuItem of its parent.
    ///     Focus drives Selection, but not vice versa.  This will enable 
    ///     focusless menus.
    /// </summary>
    internal bool IsSelected
    { 
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, BooleanBoxes.Box(value)); } 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    ///     DependencyProperty for IsSelected property.
    /// </summary>
    internal static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
            Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner( 
                    typeof(MenuItem),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 
                            BooleanBoxes.FalseBox, 
                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsSelectedChanged)));
```

Why is it not available for triggers then?

Comment: Also checked `MenuItem` class for `IsSelected` property, but didn't see this code (VS2010 .Net 4.0). I can suggest you to use `IsHighlighted` property instead, I think it's appropriate for that case.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I had to use the teamplate from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=VS.90).aspx and edit IsHighligthed, and it worked. I didnt get it to work without the controltemplate. Thanks for your help anyways. I'm still curious why my questions value can't be set and if anyone knows why go ahead and answer my question!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Anyway for trigger opened `MenuItems` you can use `IsSubmenuOpened` property. It'll be good to change background only for opened menuitems, not for all highlighted.

Comment: True! Thank you :)